# disable drupal date validation

Tags: validation, drupal, date, drupal-7

I have a date field (widget = select list) in a drupal 7 content type, And I want to be able to enter a date like 2012/2/31 without any validation error? 
what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `2012/2/31` is not a date, it's just a text string that resembles the formatting of a real date.

If you don't want to use proper, valid dates, then you simply shouldn't be using a date field. I'd advise adding a text field instead and then using the [Field validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module to define a pattern to test the input against. That way you can accept any kind of string that resembles a date, not just real dates.

Answer (score -1):

You can use date module, it provides you a date picker widget and output will be same as 2012/2/31, either you have to use textfield widget.

- [Date Module](http://drupal.org/project/date)